# Is there a way to update certain block(s) for objects on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since S3 is a block storage system, is there a way to update specific block(s) instead of the whole object? If so how can this be done?

Comment: s3 is an object storage mechanism...

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/compare/the-difference-between-block-file-object-storage/ S3 is object storage, **not** block storage.

Answer (score 1):

S3 is an object storage system, not a block storage system (like EBS).

No, you can't update part of an S3 object. You have to replace the entire object.